# The counter between the slide and the buttons below isn’t the same, in React component

Tags: reactjs, slider, gsap

I'm quite new with React and I hope that someone could help me with this issue. I don't understand why the count between the buttons and the current slide is not the same, actually the count of slides start with the numer 2 and when I arriving to the last slide the count should starting again but I just can see the slide section empty (not the slide number 0 - array position). Perhaps you can understand the problem better by reading the code below. Thanks in advance

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import gsap from 'gsap';

const Section = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;


const ClickableProjectSlides = () => {
  const sliderRef = useRef(null);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const projectData = [
    {
      title: 'Project 1',
      description: 'Description of Project 1',
    },
    {
      title: 'Project 2',
      description: 'Description of Project 2',
    },
    {
      title: 'Project 3',
      description: 'Description of Project 3',
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    const slider = sliderRef.current;
    const slideWidth = slider.clientWidth;
    gsap.to(slider, { x: -currentIndex * slideWidth, duration: 0.5 });
  }, [currentIndex]);

  const goToSlide = ((index) => {
    console.log(`goToSlide INDEX == ` + index)
    setCurrentIndex(index);
  });

  const prevSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => {
      const newIndex = prevIndex === 0 ? projectData.length - 1 : prevIndex - 1;
      console.log(`prevIndex == ${prevIndex}`)
      console.log(`newIndex == ${newIndex}`);
      console.log(`projectData.length == ${projectData.length}`);
      return newIndex;
    });
  };

  const nextSlide = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((prevIndex) => {
      const newIndex = prevIndex === projectData.length - 1 ? 0 : prevIndex + 1;
      console.log(`newIndex == ${newIndex}`);
      console.log(`prevIndex == ${prevIndex}  -  projectData.length == ${projectData.length - 1}`);

      return newIndex;
    });
  };

  return (
    <Section>
      <Container>
        <div className="slider-container">
          <div className="slider" ref={sliderRef}>
            {projectData.map((project, index) => (
              <div
                className="slide"
                key={index}
                onClick={() => goToSlide(index)}>
                <h2>{project.title}</h2>
                <p>{project.description}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="slide-buttons">
            <div className="slider-prev">
              <button className="slider-prev-btn" onClick={prevSlide}></button>
            </div>
            {projectData.map((_, index) => (
              <button
                key={index}
                onClick={() => goToSlide(index)}
                className={index === currentIndex ? 'active slider-button' : 'slider-button'}>
                { `Project ${index + 1}` }
              </button>
            ))}
            <div className="slider-next">
              <button className="slider-next-btn" onClick={nextSlide}></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </Section>
  );
};

export default ClickableProjectSlides;
```

I tried fixing the issue working on the const nexIndex on the prevSlide and the nextSlide

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
const nextSlide=()=>{
setCurrentIndex((prevIndex)=>{
  const newIndex=(prevIndex+1)%projectData.length;
  return newIndex;
});};
```